# Maximum size of bulk create (or update) for Cloudant?

Tags: rest, cloudant

When using [bulk operation](https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#bulk-operations) with Cloudant. Is there a "hard" limit (size of all documents / number of documents)?

Also: is there a best practice setting? (size of all documents / number of documents per request)?

Answer (score 2):

I understand there is a 65Mb limit in the size of individual documents in Cloudant. Having said that, I would try to avoid getting *anywhere near* that size of document.

A rule of thumb would be if the size of your documents is over a few tens of kilobytes, you might be better creating more documents and retrieving them using a view.

In terms of bulk operations, I tend to use batches of 500 documents. Bulk operations are a much more efficient way of transferring data between your client software and Cloudant and a 500 document batch size (as long as your document size is reasonable) is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: I think the question is about the total size of the request, not the maximum size of an individual document. Presumably because Cloudant charges only one API request for the entire bulk operation, so it would be cheaper to put as many documents as possible into one request. (I'd also like to know this...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such number that says, how many documents we can update in bulk, but There is a size limit of 1 MB for whole bulk document request object of **1 MB** for whole request. if requested data is more than 1 MB then request will be rejected.

As I tested myself with JsonObject with 12 fields, it took around 2K documents to cover 1MB size. But still it can be vary if you small & large content.

[Click here for more information](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/cloudant-best-and-worst-practices-part-2) under **Rule 14: Use the bulk API**