# Is there a way to do asynch calls recursively with only one callback call?

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, recursion, cloudant

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to do an asynch call recursively in javascript. I am trying to upload bulk data to a cloudant database 500 items at a time. I do not know how many documents long the json will be (somewhere between 2000-4000) so I created a recursive function to split it into chunks of 500 and upload.

```
insertDBBulkData: function(trgtDB, dbDocData, callback) {

    // if length > 500, recursively upload 500 at a time
    if(dbDocData.length > 500) {
        console.log("File too big. Length " + dbDocData.length)
        module.exports.insertDBBulkData(trgtDB, dbDocData.slice(500, dbDocData.length), function(err, body) {
            if(err) {   
                console.log(err);
                callback(err, body)
            } else {
                // only callback on last one
                callback(err, body);
            }
        });

        dbDocData = dbDocData.slice(0, 500);
    }

    trgtDB.bulk({"docs": dbDocData}, function(err, body) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully uploaded " + dbDocData.length + " users. ")
            callback(null, "Success!")
        }
    });
},
```

The issue is: since I don't know which call will finish last, I don't know when to send a response back to the server (which I can only do once). I have tried using Promises but as far as I know I can't use Promises with this recursive method because I don't have a fixed number of times the method will be called. Is this something that could be achieved with deferred promises?

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

## Solution:

Thanks to Jonas W. I was able to perform this with multiple promises in a for loop. It doesn't use recursion but works a lot better. Here is my solution:

```
insertDBBulkData: function(trgtDB, dbDocData, callback) {
    const promises = [];

    for(let start = 0; start < dbDocData.length; start += 500) {
        console.log("File too big. Index: " + start);

        var dbBulkDataPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            trgtDB.bulk({"docs": dbDocData.slice(start, start+500)}, function(err, body) {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve("Success")
                }
            });
        });

        promises.push(dbBulkDataPromise);
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
        console.log(values);
        var completed = true;

        for (message in values) {
            if (message != "Success") {
                completed = false;
            }
        }

        if (completed) {
            callback(null, values)
        } else {
            console.log("Partial upload")
            callback("Partial upload only", null)
        }


    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error uploading data: " + err);
        callback(err, null)
    });
},
```

Comment: You are inserting everything into the database in parallel, just in different chunks. Is that really what younwanted to do? Or did you planned to do it one after another?

Comment: Everything can be inserted in parallel because I query it later to sort it.

Comment: Why do you split it up into multiple calls then?

Comment: One cloudant db call for all the data is much too large to send at once. It gives me an error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937631/maximum-size-of-bulk-create-or-update-for-cloudant

Comment: can you send total count with group of data and kind of update received count

Comment: @Stakshi I was thinking that but I wanted to see if there was a better solution. Jonas W. gave an awesome one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap the insertion of one bulk into a promise:

```
function insert(docs) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      trgtDB.bulk({ docs }, function(err, body) {
        if(err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
           console.log("Successfully uploaded " + docs.length + " users. ")
           resolve("Success!")
       }
   });
  });
}
```

Now you can go over the big bulk data, slice it into chunks, start an insertion for each and then await all the promises:

```
const promises = [], size = 500;

for(let start = 0; start < dbDocData.length; start += size)
  promises.push(insert( dbDocData.slice(start, start + size) ));

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log("all done");
}).catch(/* handle errors */);
```

Comment: This is awesome! Works perfectly. I will update the question with my full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example using promises:

```js
    function insertData(trgtDB, dbDocData, callback) {
      var batchSize = 500;

      while (dbDocData.length > 0) {
        var batch = dbDocData.slice(0, batchSize);
        dbDocData.splice(0, batchSize);

        insertBatch(targetDB, dbDocData.slice(500, dbDocData.length))
          .then(function(result) {
            // everything inserted just fine
            if (dbDocData.length < 1){
              callback(yourParams);
            }
          })
          .error(function(err) {
            // handle your error
          });
      }

    }

    function insertBatch(trgtBD, batch) {
      // return a new promise 
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // load into the db
        trgtDB.bulk({
          "docs": batch
        }, function(err, body) {
          if (err) {
            // there was an error reject the promise
            reject(err);
          } else {
            // everything is good, 
            resolve("Success!")
          }
        });
      })
    }
```